# Sign in as a different Box user

Tags: objective-c, ios, box-api

I am trying to integrate my iPad app with Box. I am having an issue with the Box API where files in the account of one user are returned for some other user. Here are the steps to reproduce this issue:

1. Make the authorization calls and get the access token as mentioned in [this](http://developers.box.com/oauth/) guide. For login, I am opening the Box login page in Safari. I have the specified a custom url scheme for the redirect url, which opens up my app after the user logs in.
2. Once you get the access token, make a call to list the contents of the root folder. This succeeds.
3. Delete the app from  the iPad and rebuild it.
4. Again go to the login process (as in step 1), but this time use a different Box account to login. You get a new access code and OAuth token this time.
5. If you make the call to list the files using the new token, you will get the response from the earlier account. Ideally it should return the files for the currently authorized user.

Does Box use just OAuth to return response or does it use cookies as well? Because after authentication and receiving the access token, I also see a cookie from Box (verified using `[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedStorage] cookies]`).

I have tried repeating the above process by deleting all Box cookies before starting the authentication flow. Also, I am not saving the OAuth token on disk and retrieving it. I am not saving/caching the response in any way.

One more thing that I have noticed is that there can be two Box users logged in at once in Safari. Also, if I make the authentication request, get the access token and again make the authentication request, it shows the login page again (instead of showing the allow/deny access page). Is this intentional?

*I am using the Box v2 API and iOS 5/6*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further inspection, the problem seems to be with Box servers caching response. I did a quick test with curl using two different access tokens created from the iPad app. I made a call to fetch the user files for the root folder using both tokens. The results were correct, i.e. I got the correct files for each account.

When I did the same test on the iPad app, the files for one user were returned for the other user. If I maintained a considerable gap between the two logins, I got the correct files.

To permanently fix this, I am setting the `Cache-Control` header to `no-cache` for the request to fetch the user's files.

But it is strange that I have to do this. Box needs to check their cache validation logic IMHO.